# Send message to citrix client driver

Tags: c#, citrix, receiver, xenapp

I download SDK from here [SDK](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/virtual-channel-sdks/virtual-channel-sdk.html). The vdovern custom virtual channel Client/Server project is successfully run. Now i want to communication between c# application and vdovern.dll(citrix client driver).

[[SendMessage]](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage) API use for a send message from c# app to citrix client driver. but sendmessage API need HWND.

How to get window handle(citrix client driver) to send message from c# application to vdovern.dll(citrix client driver)?

Is there any other way to send message to citrix client driver?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citrix has provided virtual channel sdks, user can download the sdk from citrix website. It comes with some sample code and good documentation. SDKs has 2 components a server side executable and a client driver dll. when this exeutable is launched it loads client side driver in its context and creates a virtual cahnnel. User can pass data from server to client using these 2 components. Steps to build these components are given below:

http://ajdevtech.blogspot.com/2019/01/working-with-citrix-virtual-channel-sdk.html